# Reading from text file into list

Tags: c#, list

I need some help. Basically, I have a paragraph of text in a text file, and I need to read the textfile (stored as a string) into a List of characters and stores the amount of time they appear inside the string. So it will produce a list between (A-Z) and order it depending on how many times the characters appear. Is there a way to do this without using LINQ.

Thank you :)

Comment: What have you tried? You need to post an actual problem that you need help with, not a generic task for someone else to do for you.

Comment: Sorry, I can only do this in LINQ and I need another method to do it.

Comment: @Qnan: Because this is likely homework or an interview question.

Comment: @SteveGuidi yep, and there're always ppl willing to do someone else`s homework :)

Comment: Noo, this is neither homework or interview question.. I am trying to teach someone a different method to using LINQ.

Comment: Why would you try teaching someone something you don't know? Better question: Why would someone be willing to learn something from someone that doesn't know it?

Comment: -1 for asking further question (like sorting) after your question has been answered, without showing any effort to customize it for your needs.

Comment: Whoa whoa guys, back off a bit. lol and I did show effort: "listofchars.Sort (delegate(KeyValuePair<char, double> x, KeyValuePair<char, double> y) { return x.Value.CompareTo(y.Value); }); "

Comment: @Phorce if it works no problem, if not, then post another question instead of asking new questions in comments.

Comment: @L.B But then I get moaned at for asking questions that could have been asked in the previous question? I cannot win. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An efficient and easy way is to create a [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) with the char as key and the number it appears as value. It has the nice [AddOrUpdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378675.aspx)(upsert) method:

```
string text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
var chars = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<char, int>();
foreach (char c in text)
{
   chars.AddOrUpdate(c, 1, (chr, count) => count + 1);
}
```

If you want to order it by the number without Linq(Lambda != Linq) you can use this code:

```
List<KeyValuePair<char, int>> charList = chars.ToList();
charList.Sort((firstPair, nextPair) =>
{
    return firstPair.Value.CompareTo(nextPair.Value);
});
```

**Edit**: If you want to order descending change above a little bit:

```
charList.Sort((firstPair, nextPair) =>
{
    return -(firstPair.Value.CompareTo(nextPair.Value));
});
```

result:

```
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, charList.Select(kv => string.Format("Char={0} Num={1}", kv.Key, kv.Value))));

Char=  Num=90
Char=e Num=59
Char=t Num=43
Char=s Num=39
Char=n Num=38
Char=i Num=32
Char=a Num=28
Char=o Num=25
Char=r Num=24
Char=p Num=18
Char=m Num=18
Char=l Num=17
Char=u Num=17
Char=d Num=16
Char=h Num=14
Char=y Num=13
Char=g Num=11
Char=c Num=10
Char=k Num=7
Char=w Num=6
Char=f Num=6
Char=I Num=6
Char=v Num=5
Char=b Num=5
Char=L Num=5
Char=, Num=4
Char=. Num=4
Char=0 Num=3
Char=x Num=2
Char=1 Num=2
Char=' Num=1
Char=5 Num=1
Char=M Num=1
Char=A Num=1
Char=P Num=1
Char=6 Num=1
Char=9 Num=1
```

Comment: But you cannot convert "chars" to list, only string?

Comment: Sorry - I don't quite follow. Have you tested the code?

Comment: I'm on monodevelop.. http://pastebin.com/myZUjLhs is the code (it's in main) I get 'Type 'Systems.Collections.ConcurrentDictionary<char, int>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList''

Comment: @Phorce: Sorry, you'd need to add `using System.Linq` for `ToList`. If you want to avoid that you need to create the list manually with a loop. Note that i've just edited my amswer to show how to sort the list descending.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for your reply.. Can I use the .Where statement when I'm adding or updating? So e.g. chars.AddOrUpdate (c, 1, (chr, count) => count + 1).Where(t => Char.IsLetter(t));

Comment: @Phorce: But that would indeed be Linq. Anyway, it would be easier(and free of linq) if you would add this check before: `if(Char.IsLetter(c))
                    chars.AddOrUpdate(c, 1, (chr, count) => count + 1);`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using a hashtable.

```
Hashtable listofChars = new Hashtable();

for () { // your loop for the chars in the file
        Char c ; // your char
        if (!listofChars.ContainsKey(c))
        {
            listofChars[c] = 1;
        }
        else {
            listofChars[c] = ((int)listofChars["c"]) + 1;
        } 
}
```

**--EDIT--**

```
var listofChars = new SortedDictionary<char, int>();
foreach(char c in File.ReadAllText(fileName))
{
    if (!listofChars.ContainsKey(c))
    {
        listofChars[c] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        listofChars[c] += 1;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a `Dictionary<char,int>` be better?

Comment: yes, it is better. I have wrote the first solution came to my mind.

Comment: I edited your answer, feel free to delete it if you don't like.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I used yours @L.B - Am I able to still .sort? listofchars.Sort (delegate(KeyValuePair<char, double> x, KeyValuePair<char, double> y) {
    return x.Value.CompareTo(y.Value); });

Comment: @Phorce you can use `SortedDictionary` instead of `Dictionary`

Comment: SortedDictionary appears to sort lowest-to-highest what about the reverse of this? I cannot use LINQ.. Couldn't I just convert the dictionary to a list?